# when can a function serve as its own correction for finding its roots via an iteration function? what is it called in this case?

Tags: fixed-point-theorems, fixed-point-iteration, fixed-points

What are the criteria such that a function $f(t)$ can serve as the correction in an iteration function of the form $g (t) = t - \lambda f (t)$ where $\lambda$ is some relaxation factor? It is almost reminiscent of Newton's iteration, without the derivative.

for instance, if $f(t)=sin(t)$ then $g(t)$ has attractive fixed-points at $t=n\pi$ when $n$ is even and repulsive fixed-points when $n$ is odd

if the iteration is $g (t) = t + \lambda f (t)$ then the attractiveness and repulsiveness of the fixed-points is swapped, so in the case of $f(t)=sin(t)$  it would be  repulsive when $n$ is even and attractive when $n$ is odd

Do functions which have this property have a special name?

Perhaps the iteration converges to a root $f(t)=0$ where the derivative is $0<f'(t)<2$.

and iterating the function $t-Z(t)$ doesn't converge to any points where Z'(t) is not in [0,2] .. at least for the first 20 odd-numbers zeros I checked.. this table demonstrates

the column on the left is the difference between the starting point (the $2n-1$th zero -0.1 and the 50 iterations of the iteration function, and the column on the right is the derivative of $Z$ evaluated at the $2n-1$th zero

$ \left[ \begin {array}{cc}  0.0& 0.7931604332\\  0.0
& 1.371721287\\  0.0& 1.382119539
\\  0.0& 1.490610763\\  0.0&
 1.568031477\\ - 1.11005001& 2.426579069
\\  0.0& 1.391805619\\ -
 0.38497400& 2.287779010\\ - 0.59958219& 2.186311017
\\ - 0.00000004& 1.779555993\\ -
 0.98459094& 2.637886209\\ - 0.48377276& 2.161778835
\\ - 0.32348014& 2.176460788\\ 
 0.0& 1.479402184\\ - 1.37854250& 3.515767073
\\ - 0.3298843& 2.167414624\\ 
{\it Float}(\infty )& 2.982497202\\  0.0&
 1.361150829\\ - 14.4201635& 3.119005954
\\ - 0.3041748& 2.294939525\end {array} \right]
$

I'm sure I would find the same thing with iteration function $t+Z(t)$ .

To "Fix" this, one can take $t-tanh(f(t))$ then the derivative can be no more than 2.. see [does this Newton-like iterative root finding method based on the hyperbolic tangent function have a name?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2142892/does-this-newton-like-iterative-root-finding-method-based-on-the-hyperbolic-tang)

It is the set of functions whose derivative at the roots is less than 2 and greater than 0. If anyone had a great idea on how to prove this....it is a conjecture based on the empirical fact that iterating this method with the Hardy Z function results in convergence when the derivative at the starting point is 0

Comment: So that would be, _functions whose derivative at the roots is $1$_?

Comment: @leftaroundabout not sure about that, take the Hardy Z function for instance. you can find roots this way but the derivative at its roots is not 1. it seems if the derivative is 1 then that corresponds to a superattractive fized-point (multiplier 0) where the multiplier is the derivative of the iteration function evaluated at the root

Comment: "It is basically Newton's iteration, without the derivative" is a little exaggerate, don't you think ?

Comment: @JeanMarie lol. not really.  $t-f(t)/f'(t)$ vs $t-f(t)$ ? delete the derivative and replace it with 1, then you have crow's iteration. i should have said its the relaxed Newton iteration without the derivative perhaps

Comment: Let us share some humor: A step more, I delete $f(t)$ in $t-f(t)$, it remains $t$ which, by transitivity is still close to Newton's iteration :)

Comment: @JeanMarie Hmm, but Im not sure the identity map can be used to find roots, and every point is a fixed-point of the identity :) Ok updated, it only almost resembles Newton's iteration

Comment: @leftaroundabout your comment made me think.. maybe it is , functions whose derivative at the roots is less than 2 and greater than 0

Comment: You didn't define what you are looking for.  Is it roots of $f(t)$?  How is $g$ derived from $f$?  This is a nonsense question. You could certainly ask when an iteration of $t_{i+1}=t-\lambda f(t)$ as a search for roots of $f(t)$ will succeed, which is my wild guess to be what you are asking.  Then think about the requirement of the derivative of the iteration function to see where this works.  -1 and I wish I could minus more.

Answer (score 1):

The crux of your method is the $\lambda$ factor. It is a variation of "trial and error". It is a perfectly valid method when used with caution. I don't know of any particular name for it but it is a very simple and natural method. The effectiveness of the method can be improved by adjusting the $\lambda$ factor depending on how close $f(t)$ is to zero and perhaps other data. One example of this is Newton's method as mentioned in a comment.